# SharePoint 2007 | How to Enable a Disabled Field if a Checkbox is Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2007

Hi Want to know what I'm missing...

```
function executeMe(){

if(document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_ef941f4a_7f2d_4a75_a119_6f009e7a22ad_ctl00_ctl04_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00").checked{

document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_ef941f4a_7f2d_4a75_a119_6f009e7a22ad_ctl00_ctl04_ctl03_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField").disabled=false;

}else{

document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_ef941f4a_7f2d_4a75_a119_6f009e7a22ad_ctl00_ctl04_ctl03_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField").disabled=true;

}
```

When I check the button it's still disabled.

Answer (score 0):

your code should be like this. change the IDs once again as per your above code.

```
    function executeMe()
 {
   if(document.getElementById("chkbox").checked)
   {
       document.getElementById("Text1").disabled=true;
   }
   else
   {
      document.getElementById"Text1").disabled=false;
   }
 }
```

This should work !!

Comment: Your answer would be more readable if you didn't put everything on one line. You can use as many lines for code as you need, just put four spaces at the start of each line.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, for helping me on this. today is the first time when i become a member of Stackoverflow.com